# How can i convert time to minutes using Sql queries e.g "02:30:05' to 150.5 minutes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a billing system and its based on time-in and time-out. Rate is R5 per 30 minutes charged to users for loaning an item.

I managed to get the Time difference and got time as "02:30:05" now how can i convert this time to minutes and have "02:30:00" = "150 min" so that I can be able to divide time by 30 minutes, to be able to multiply by the rate to generate my bill. as I can not divide Date time with a number. I want something like (150 min/30 min = 5 ans) , (5 ans * 5 rate = R25 bill) I hope its clear guys i'm a beginner so please do say if I'm not making any sense. thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are yoy using? How are the time values stored (column data type)?

Comment: Show how you get this time difference

Comment: I believe that the difference is TimeSpan. If so then you can use `timeDiff.TotalMinutes` to get minutes

Comment: It would help to see the code where you get the time difference

Comment: @mybirthname time values are in time(0) "HH:mm:ss" format and  here is how i got time difference.... declare timeIn time(0), timeOut time(0)
select timeIn = '00:00:00',timeOut='11:30:00' 
declare Sec BIGINT
select Sec = DateDiff(s, timeIn, timeOut)                                                   select convert(varchar(5),sec/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),sec%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(sec%60)) as TripDuration

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Microsoft  SQL Server column data type is time(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one. it will calculate total minutes
SELECT LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TimeSpent))
  FROM yourtable
```

**TimeSpent** will be your datetime variable

Comment: this also worked a miracle thank you so much for your input :) i would be upvoting you but i havent got enough reputations to vote

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention what is your dbms I'll provide you with the syntax of SqlServer that gives the difference of 2 times on minutes:

`SELECT DateDiff(mi, @timeIN, @TimeOut)`

The first parameter allows you to choose in what datepart you need the difference.

For years write `YY`

For months write `MM`

For days write `DD`

For hours write `hh`

For minutes write `mi`

For seconds write `ss`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting time difference in **TimeSpan**. Then you can use to get total minutes:

```
timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
```

If you have the result in **string** then you must tryparse to get timespan:

```
string time = "02:30:00";
TimeSpan timeSpan;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out timeSpan))
{
     var aa = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
}
```

Comment: I will surely try this one out thank you so much for your input  cause I was working in sql queries and I would love to be able to work in C# as well in my controller i would be upvoting you but i havent got enough reputations to vote